# Выполнить функцию во время объявления переменной

Tags: javascript

Я делаю во время выполнения кода так, чтобы получить значение из функции:

```
var dis = function calcD(a, b, c) {
   return b*b - 4*a*c;
};

dis = dis(-4, 2, 1);
```

Затем можно просто вызывать `dis`, у которого будет конкретное значение.
Так вот, как можно сразу заставить выполнить скрипт calcD и засунуть в переменную без дополнительной строчки `dis = dis(-4, 2, 1);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var dis = (function calcD(a, b, c) {
   return b*b - 4*a*c;
})(-4, 2, 1);

console.log(dis);
```

Однако это как-то всё бесполезненько и бестолково...ибо с такой же легкостью можно вообще не городить эту функцию и написать `dis = b*b - 4*a*c;`

Comment: Видимо нужно было написать, что функция делает только `return 2+2`, чтобы бесполезность не была заметна на примере)) Не для такого такой способ мне нужен. Спасибо.

Comment: А функция при этом недоступна, да? То есть имя функции никак в текущем скопе не доступно и считай, что имя указывать бессмысленно?

Comment: И зачем вы обрамляете функцию скобочками, если можно так написать `var var1 = function(){//...}();`? Стиль или необходимость?

Comment: `имя указывать бессмысленно` - да ....... `зачем вы обрамляете функцию скобочками` - просто визуально отделить функцию с телом от её вызова........`чтобы бесполезность не была заметна на примере` - хотя может там где в отдельном модуле может такое понадобиться, я хз,)

Comment: Как раз в модуле и [использую](http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2017/02/01/0001/0403/94611/11/e1f4c3ea6f.png) такую переменную, при вызове которого в переменную заносится ширина скролла браузера.